# Poster by using tikzposter with picture added

Tags: posters

I'm trying to design a poster using `tikzposter` but I find it very difficult to control the position of the images. To give an idea, I'm trying to create something similar to the below poster using tikz

[image]

Comment: almost all your previous questions have been answered but you have not accepted any answer (except one)-- please appreciate the time and effort of other members

Comment: I do accept if the answer helped to resolve the problem